# How to create a blank datetime object? So I can find the average of the time deltas

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, date-arithmetic

I have converted current time stamps into datetime objects and I am able to subtract them. My problem is that I need to sum up all of the deltas but I am unable to create a "blank" datetime object. For example 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000

```
    low_sum_time_alert_fired_to_closed = 0
    low_sum_time_investigate_open_to_closed = 0
    low_sum_time_alert_fired_to_investigation = 0
    low_sum_time_alert_fired_to_first_assignment = 0
#  iterate through the row index's
    for idx in range(amt_of_rows):
        # Index the row of the dataframe
        row = df.iloc[idx]
        vendor_name = row[2]
        #  formatting the timestamps
        insert_at = datetime.strptime(row[3], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
        first_assignment = datetime.strptime(row[4], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
        first_investigated = datetime.strptime(row[5], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
        time_closed = datetime.strptime(row[6], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")

        if row[0] == "LOW":
            num_low += 1
####### THIS IS WHERE THINGS BREAK SINCE I'M TRYING TO ADD THE DIFFERENCE OF THE TIME STAMPS TO AN INTEGER ###
            low_sum_time_alert_fired_to_closed += time_closed - insert_at 
            low_sum_time_investigate_open_to_closed += time_closed - first_investigated
            low_sum_time_alert_fired_to_investigation += first_investigated - insert_at
            low_sum_time_alert_fired_to_first_assignment += first_assignment - insert_at

    low_sum_time_alert_fired_to_closed = low_sum_time_alert_fired_to_closed/amt_of_rows
    low_sum_time_investigate_open_to_closed = low_sum_time_investigate_open_to_closed/amt_of_rows
    low_sum_time_alert_fired_to_investigation = low_sum_time_alert_fired_to_investigation/amt_of_rows
    low_sum_time_alert_fired_to_first_assignment = low_sum_time_alert_fired_to_first_assignment/amt_of_rows
```

Comment: You cannot make datetime in 0000-00-00 00:00:00.00 format as it is invalid format

Answer (score 3):

To sum all `timedelta`s you need to start from a blank `timedelta`, rather than `datetime`.

just start from `datetime.timedelta(0)`.

simple example:

```py
import datetime

td0 = datetime.timedelta(0)

td1 = datetime.timedelta(hours=1, minutes=1, seconds=1)
td2 = datetime.timedelta(hours=2, minutes=2, seconds=2)
td3 = datetime.timedelta(hours=3, minutes=3, seconds=3)

td0 += td1
td0 += td2
td0 += td3

print(td0)
```

Output:

```
6:06:06
```

Comment: Awesome I will try this! now the  reason I am summing all of them is so  I can find the average. How would I divide a  timedelta object by an integer or is that even possible?